# Got issue with apple certificate request

Tags: ios

I got a weird problem with certificate request that I submit successfully, but when trying to approve it, Apple said that...error without any detailed description in the history tab.

I did it many times, these steps are quite easy and always success but this time. I double checked all related things about how to generate CSR that: AWDRCA, email, OCSP, Key size...etc everything seems right.

Anybody meet this problem please help me.

Comment: It seem the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug that a *lot* of people are hitting at the moment. There's no known workaround yet, but you can follow along with the [developer forums thread about it](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/144551).

As of around 17:00 GMT 12th March 2012, this is now fixed.

Comment: Thanks Mattjgalloway, I had thought that is an Apple's bug since I have tried to generate CSR and submit using 2 MAC but got a same error.